# Standalone Project Login with WP Login

Tags: plugins

We want to install Wordpress and put our StandAlone Application in a Subfolder. The StandAlone Application has it's own Usermanagement and LanguageHandling (should be independent)

When the administator logs into the WP-Admin area, he should also be logged into the StandAlone Application.

We are new to Wordpress, but thought about a event which triggers if the Administrator logs into the WP-Admin area. ( with a Plugin? )

Is this a possible and good solution, could this be insecure, are there plugins to do this (haven't found any).

Answer (score 0):

Turn your Wordpress site into an OAuth provider ( [link](https://github.com/justingreerbbi/wordpress-oauth-server/blob/master/README.md) ). Thus, your app users can login with WP accounts.

Or, the other way round, make your app an OAuth provider.